# Converting UTC time to local in python datetime.time

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, utc

My sample dataframe is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':['00:00:00','03:00:00','06:00:00','09:00:00','12:00:00'],
              'value':[850,np.nan,500,650,780]})
```

Here, the time are in UTC, I want to convert the time to local time such that:

`Local time = UTC + 5:15`

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Suggest you search for 'Python Time zone Conversion' do not try and write code to do this manually, find a library that handles it.  time zone conversion is hard to get right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas time shift from utc to local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814201/pandas-time-shift-from-utc-to-local)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)?

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'time':['00:00:00','03:00:00','06:00:00','09:00:00','12:00:00'],
...               'value':[850,np.nan,500,650,780]})
>>> df
       time  value
0  00:00:00  850.0
1  03:00:00    NaN
2  06:00:00  500.0
3  09:00:00  650.0
4  12:00:00  780.0
>>> df['time'] = df['time'].astype('datetime64')
>>> df
                 time  value
0 2021-06-14 00:00:00  850.0
1 2021-06-14 03:00:00    NaN
2 2021-06-14 06:00:00  500.0
3 2021-06-14 09:00:00  650.0
4 2021-06-14 12:00:00  780.0
>>> d = timedelta(hours=5, minutes=15)
>>> print(d)
5:15:00
>>> df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda v: v+d)
>>> df
                 time  value
0 2021-06-14 05:15:00  850.0
1 2021-06-14 08:15:00    NaN
2 2021-06-14 11:15:00  500.0
3 2021-06-14 14:15:00  650.0
4 2021-06-14 17:15:00  780.0
>>> df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda v: v.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
>>> df
       time  value
0  05:15:00  850.0
1  08:15:00    NaN
2  11:15:00  500.0
3  14:15:00  650.0
4  17:15:00  780.0
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ Justin. solved my problem.